# User home folder size limit

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, xubuntu

I am trying to find anything on the web no success.
Is there any way to limit size of home directory for user ? 
Or any directory ? 
The best would be by percentage for two users 45% and 45%. 
But by gigabytes will be fine as well.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `/etc/fstab` with a commandline editor (vi, sed, nano) to add the `usrquota` and/or `grpquota` to the partition (depending on your needs: pick one or both)(and yes, it assumes you use a partition for  it and in this case that would be /home/):

  - userquota is for users
  - grpquouta is for groups
- Create a file for user and/or group:

  ```
  touch /home/aquota.user
  touch /home/aquota.group
  ```

  - The files need to be owned by `root` and have `600` as permissions

    sudo chown root:root /home/aquota.user
    sudo chown root:root /home/aquota.group
    sudo chmod 600 /home/aquota.user
    sudo chmod 600 /home/aquota.group
- reboot or remount the partition.
- command `quotaon -av` will enable quota
- command `edquota -u {user_id}` will let you edit them where {user_id} is the id of the user. This will open `vi` for editing the quota.

  Setting the quota is done in "blocks" or "inodes" and there are 2 options:

  - soft: Max number of blocks/inodes a user may have on the partition before a warning is issued and a grace period countdown begins.
  - hard: Max number of blocks/inodes user may have on partition. 
    (If set to zero then no limit is enforced on either of the options).

> The best would be by percentage for two users 45% and 45%. But by gigabytes will be fine as well.

- Blocks are probably 4kB (`stat -f .` will show the blocksize on your system).
- Inodes means amount of files and directories.

[Answer based on this how to](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html). The link has a lot more information about commands related to this and explains it a bit more in depth.

Comment: does this method requires `/home/` dir to be mounted on separate partition?

Comment: yes it needs a partition.